# Calling Metis using Fortran and C

Tags: c, fortran, metis

I tried to run the following code but got errors. The error is *Memory allocation failed for CreateGraphNodal: nptr.

```
program test
  implicit none
  integer, parameter   :: nels=2, nnds=6, npel=4
  integer              :: eptr(nels+1), nodes(nels*npel), epart(nels), npart(nnds), n
  integer, pointer     :: vwgt=>null(), vsize=>null(), mopts=>null()
  real(8), pointer     :: tpwgts=>null()
  eptr=(/0,4,8/)
  nodes=(/0,1,2,3,1,4,5,2/) ! Element 1 has nodes 0 1 2 3
                            ! Element 2 has nodes 1 4 5 2
  call METIS_PartMeshNodal(nels,nnds,eptr,nodes,vwgt,vsize,2,tpwgts,mopts,n,epart,npart) 
  print*, npart; print*, epart
end program test
```

And when running the code, I get this error:

```
    fobeidat@envenio05:~/Metis/metis-5.1.0/graphs$ gfortran test.f90 libmetis.a 
fobeidat@envenio05:~/Metis/metis-5.1.0/graphs$ ./a.out
   Current memory used:           0 bytes
   Maximum memory used:           0 bytes
***Memory allocation failed for CreateGraphNodal: nptr. Requested size: 68719476792 bytes
           0           0           0           0   659590448       32767
           0           0
```

Comment: Did you read the error message? It requests around **68GB**...

Comment: Do you know how handle this Stefan?

Comment: Does it work at all for smaller problems?

Comment: Three possibilities: Buy a better computer, reduce your problem to a smaller one or check your input. Unfortunately, I don't have any experience with Metis.

Comment: @Vladimir ,Metis works well from command lines, e.g., mpmetis file.mesh 5. However, when I try to use from FORTRAN code it doesn't work at all. Get segmentation fault

Comment: How did you get it to work at all? Isn't the interface C only? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730349/calling-metis-apiwrtten-in-c-language-in-fortran-program

Comment: @VladimirF, Do you have a complete example on a smaller problem ?

Comment: I also had the same problem with another example,: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20099846/calling-metis-api-using-fortran-and-c

Comment: In the other question you have completely different interface!

Comment: Have you seen the link I wrote you?